# Refresh ComboBox Items, easiest way

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I've googled a lot. Found a lot as well. Unfortunately nothing is straight, easy and most importantly, simple. I want some guy write a `method` that takes a `List<string>` and removes previous `Items`, then set this `List<string>`.

Currently I have a method but it's not error free.

```
public void refreshList(List<string> list){
    albumList.Items.Clear();
    albumList.DataSource =  list;
}
```

Comment: Maybe useful although not what you asked for (depending on what you want to do in the bigger picture): observale collections vs generic Lists..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need albumList.Items.Clear();

This code works just fine

```
public void refreshList(List<string> list){
    albumList.DataSource =  list;
}
```

Comment: New items don't appear in the list.

Comment: Yes it worked. I didn't reset the previous List. Now, I'm doing `list = null;` and then `list = new List<string>();` then I'm calling `refreshList(list);`. So, its working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 19):

For anyone still wondering.

You can use a BindlingList and BindingSource.

```
BindingList<YOUR_CLASS_TYPE> bindinglist = new BindingList<YOUR_CLASS_TYPE>()
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = bindinglist;
ComboBox.DataSource = bSource;
```

You add all items to your bindinglist and they will be automatically updated within your combobox.

If you want a sortable combobox you can construct the BindingList with a container that inherits from IList, like List that has a sort function. You can then sort that IList reference and it will be reflected again within the combobox.

Comment: There is still one problem wtih this;
If you will set the BindingList as source to a editable grid, and the same BindingList(by reference) will be used in another form just for displaying; editing the item in the grid won't refresh the items in another form.
So just to complete your answer; In the case I have described, just use
`BindingList.ResetBindings();`
to refresh the items in all controls which are using the binding list.

Comment: Yes, that is one caveat. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!!!  I had researched this for 3 hours and read a dozen posts, blogs, and MSDN articles.  I'm glad it ended in a simple fix like this rather than what a lot of these resources were recommending :)!

Comment: Combobox displays class name (with namespace) instead of values?

Comment: In relpy to the above comment, I needed to reassign the displaymember and valuemember of the combobox

Answer (score 5):

When bound to a data source,`Items.Clear();` doesn't work. This should be:

```
albumList.DataSource = list;
```

or to be sure:

```
albumList.DataSource = null;
albumList.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: Previous items aren't removed, this way. Rather, new items are append with previous.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using DataSource you need to clear items for the new list to appear.
Since you can't clear while using DataSource you need to set it to null first.

```
albumList.DataSource = null;
albumList.Items.Clear();
albumList.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a task with a similar problem like this

The initial solution to set the datasource to null and to reassign the list back to it didn't work at all. Though it did clear the items and show up the new items in the list, it made selection of any of the items in that list impossible. But upon digging around the internet, I found an old VB solution that ended up working and having the intended effect.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Clear the list object before repopulating it. See code below:

   ```
   //adding the instantiation of the list object so you know what I'm clearing
   List<string> listExample = new List<string>();
   listExample.Clear();
   ```
2. Refresh the comboBox, so that it picks up the new list. See code below:

   ```
   if (albumList.DataSource == null) 
   { 
       albumList.DataSource = listExample; 
   } 
   else 
   {
       albumList.Refresh();
   }
   ```