# Refresh comboBox when child form closed

Tags: c#, combobox, refresh, datasource

In my parent form I have comboBox populated with items using `DataTable` as `DataSource` which looks like this.

```
        sourceTypes = myDataBase.SourceType.ToList<SourceTypes>();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ID");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        foreach (SourceType sourceType in sourceTypes)
        {
            string sourceTypeName = sourceType.sourceTypeName;
            string ID = sourceType.sourceTypeID.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(sourceTypeName, ID);
        }

        comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

From my parent form I am calling my child form in which I add new record to `myDataBase` and I would want this new added record to be visible in my parent's form comboBox as soon as child form is closed. So I was thinking to call something like this from my childFrm which will refresh the comboBox.

```
        private void FrmChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
             FrmParent.refresh();
        }
```

Now I need the static refresh method in my parent form, which I can't really get to work. How could I get it done? Cheers

EDIT: Child form is opened here:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmChild frmChild = new FrmChild();
        frmChild.ShowDialog();
        frmChild.Dispose();
    }
```

EDIT2: I tried like this (no static method), but didn't work

In my Child form:

```
        private void FrmChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
             FrmParent frmParent = new FrmParent();
             frmParent.refresh();
        }
```

In my parent form, refresh method (after the new record is added to myDataBase).

```
        sourceTypes = myDataBase.SourceType.ToList<SourceTypes>();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ID");

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        foreach (SourceType sourceType in sourceTypes)
        {
            string sourceTypeName = sourceType.sourceTypeName;
            string ID = sourceType.sourceTypeID.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(sourceTypeName, ID);
        }

        comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Tried like this, combobox still doesnt get refreshed.

Comment: How is the child form opened/closed? Are you using a modal popup?

Comment: Can you confirm that your `refresh` method is working when called from the parent form itself? Is there a reason you're making it static? If you're just making it static so that you can access it from the child form then you don't have to do that as you can pass in a reference to your form instance.

Comment: @keyboardP Yes, I am making it static so I can access it from my child form. I guess it is better memory management then creating new parentForm object everytime the child form is closed.

Comment: @Whizzil - You pass your form in by reference so there won't be any noticeable difference in memory because you're not creating a new object (just creates a new reference to it). Static methods can't access non-static controls unless you're, for example, passing in your control into the method via a parameter. This could be related to your issue.

Comment: @Whizzil - You're creating a new instance of the parent form. Check my answer to see how to pass the form without creating a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your parent form to your child form and call its method. Create a constructor in your child form that takes in your parent form and don't make your `refresh` method static. Also try handling the `Closing` event instead of the `Closed` event.

FrmChild class:

```
private FrmParent parentForm = null;
public FrmChild(FrmParent pf)
{
   parentForm = pf;
}
```

Now, when `closing`, you can call the refresh method

```
private void FrmChild_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if(parentForm != null)
      parentForm.refresh();
}
```

FrmParent class

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(FrmChild frmChild = new FrmChild(this))
    {
       frmChild.ShowDialog();     
    }
}
```

Comment: @Whizzil - You're welcome :) Just one thing. Your refresh method recreates the entire datatable but this isn't necessary. You can try refreshing just the data source value as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089342/refresh-combobox-items-easiest-way