# Textbox value transfer to combobox with database

Tags: c#, database, combobox, textbox, addition

I have a Access database, two forms.

**Form1:**
Combobox (working database)
add button.

**Form2:**
textbox
add button.

I want to form1 click add button open form2, write something on `textbox` click add button save database. Now when I was click form2 add button. form1 don't `comboxbox` refresh. When I closed program and opened that time I saw. How can I do it?

Comment: refresh combobox.DataSource after closing form2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089342/refresh-combobox-items-easiest-way

Comment: In Form Activated refresh the datasouce

Answer (score 0):

You can use Combobox.Items.Refresh() after adding text in your TextBox