# Iterating through USB Drives

Tags: c#, foreach, combobox

I am iterating through all connected USB drives on the `Form_Load` event and populating them into a `Combobox`. This works fine, however, I now have a button that I want to use to refresh the list and add any to the list, that do not exist already.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {   
                string dl = d.VolumeLabel;
                string dt = Convert.ToString(d.DriveType); 

                if (comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
                {

                }  
                else
                {  
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(d.Name.Remove(2));
                }
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving Drive Information", "Error!"); }
}
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong and I need another pair of eyes, but when I have the form open and hit the button, the newly added drives do not populate into my Combobox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What (specific) part of the code shows unexpected/unwanted behaviour? Is the catch hit? Is one of the drives not `IsReady`? Is it the `Contains` nested `if` that is failing? You should be able to tell exactly what's happening by stepping through it.

Comment: Here is the answear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089342/refresh-combobox-items-easiest-way

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ When stepping through, it will get to the nested `if` statement and then completely ignore the `else`, which is what I need it to do. If the item exists, ignore it, else, add it.

Comment: Your checking if contains the combo box text...

Comment: surely in your 2nd If you should be checking for `d.Name`, and not the `comboBox1.Text` itself

Comment: @Thewads That works, however, it populates everything twice?

Comment: @Sean you haven't cleared the list from the `Form_Load` population before re-adding everything

Comment: @Thewads Thank you. I had to run a `combobox.items.clear()` before my `foreach` statement. This then (i've only tested this once), added the 'missing' drives to the list, as well as populating the others..

Comment: @Sean I have written this up as an answer with a couple of other suggested improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd If you should be checking for `d.Name`, and not the `comboBox1.Text` itself. You are also not clearing the list after initial population from `Form_Load`

I would suggest pulling out the population code into its own method and calling from both `Form_Load` and `btnRefresh_Click` rather than duplicating the logic.

The new method would look something like this:

```
private void PopulateDrives()
{
    try
    {
        combobox.items.clear()
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {   
                string dl = d.VolumeLabel;
                string dt = Convert.ToString(d.DriveType); 

                comboBox1.Items.Add(d.Name.Remove(2));
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving Drive Information", "Error!"); }
}
```

You would then simply call `PopulateDrives()` from both places.  I have also just inverted your 2nd if statement to tidy it up a little

Comment: The problem, not the improvements, is exactly my answer, which I posted 7 minutes before you....

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;`
 `comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;` should be outside the `foreach()` and `if (d.IsReady == true)` can be rewritten to `if (d.IsReady)`

Comment: @user2754599 Why does it need to be outside of the `foreach` statement?
Surely, where it is now, has the same effect regardless?

Comment: @Sean well it's not `necessary`, but why would would you do this for each driveinfo you find? it's bad practise

Comment: @user2754599 I've changed this accordingly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
```

is checking if comboBox1 contains comboBox1's title text, which it does.

You should be checking if it contains either `dl` or `dt` or `d.Name`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady)
            {   
                string dl = d.VolumeLabel;
                string dt = Convert.ToString(d.DriveType); 
                comboBox1.Items.Add(d.Name.Remove(2));
            }
        }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving Drive Information", "Error!"); }
}
```

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I thought it was to check if the item already existed (am I wrong?) and I replaced it by clearing the comboBox1